# ¿Cómo añadir diferentes dataframes a un excel en diferentes sheets?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Estoy intentando unir dos dataframes que provienen de una pivot table, pero a la hora de ponerlos en un mismo excel se me eliminan algunas columnas.

Adjunto código:

```
data_ota_MEU=data_ota_MEU.pivot_table(index=['pos_arr_type','carrier'], columns='week', values='Index', aggfunc="sum")
data_ota_SEU=data_ota_SEU.pivot_table(index=['pos_arr_type','carrier'], columns='week', values='Index', aggfunc="sum")
data_ota_UK=data_ota_UK.pivot_table(index=['pos_arr_type','carrier'], columns='week', values='Index', aggfunc="sum")

excel = pd.ExcelWriter(path+file_name)
data_ota_MEU.to_excel(excel, sheet_name='OTA_MEU', index=False)
data_ota_SEU.to_excel(excel, sheet_name='OTA_SEU', index=False)
data_ota_UK.to_excel(excel, sheet_name='OTA_UK', index=False)


excel.save()
excel.close()
```

Resultado:
Únicamete me aparece la columna '*week*' con los **values**.
No me aparecen las columnas **index**.

Resultado esperado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado obtenido:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y no olvides leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Visita también el  [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, he modificado la pregunta a ver si es más clara @Esei

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que se le esta diciendo explicitamente a pandas que omita el index:
`index=False` en
`df.to_excel(excel, sheet_name='name', index=False)`

Hay dos opciones.

- O se pone con `True`: `df.to_excel(excel, sheet_name='name', index=True)`
- O simplemente se omite este parametro: `df.to_excel(excel, sheet_name='name')`